# How to properly perform press option with pyautogui?

Tags: python, loops, pyautogui

I am trying to perform a twelve times `.press()` action over `tab` button using `pyautogui` library.

Here's what I got so far:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press(['tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab'], 0.01)
```

Which throws the next error:

```
  File "path", line 42, in <module>
    pyautogui.press(['tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab'], 0.01)

  File "path", line 586, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)

  File "path", line 1594, in press
    for i in range(presses):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Is there any way to accomplish this task by using a loop? or any other simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for loop, or you could add an argument to make presses 12. I'm also assuming the .01 relates to the interval you want, which requires the interval key word.

```
import pyautogui

for x in range(12):
    pyautogui.press('tab', interval=.01)
```

or

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.press('tab', interval=.01, presses=12)
```

When you put them all in the press command as a list (like you had before), it tries to press them all at the same time, instead of pressing the tab key 12 times, which I think is what you want